# using an instance variable in static block

Tags: java, static

Would this code result in  a run time error? (have used some android libraries, but I do not think this is platform specific)

```
class A
{
Context sContext;      
public A()
   {
   //initialize sContext here
   }
 public static Conext getContext()
   {
   return sContext;
   }
}

class B
{
 public static Context anotherContext;
static
  {
   anotherContext = A.getContext();

  }
}
```

The confusing part is when using eclipse debugger,

```
A.getContext()
```

evaluates to a non-null value.

However

```
anotherContext
```

evaluates to null

Does anyone have any idea about this behaviour ?
Thanks

Edit :

My bad, sContext  is a static variable, but it is being assigned a value only in an instance method as in

```
public void onCreate()
{
sContext = getApplicationContext();
}
```

So in this case what  would the behaviour be?

Comment: No, it will not result in a run-time error. It won't even compile, as far as I can tell. Have you tried it?

Comment: `error: non-static variable sContext cannot be referenced from a static context`

Answer (score 0):

this will not even compile. it will give you error

> "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"

because you are trying to access an instance variable from static block, this would have run had the `initializer block` been non-static or the variable were `static`.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. `anotherContext` is not static, and so can't be retrieved from the static method `getContext`. If you want to get the context inited, do so in a static init block.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an instance variable from a static method. Remember that a static method has no knowledge about any particular instantiations of your class. It simply exists as a method of your class in general. In other words, your

```
public static Conext getContext() {
    return sContext;
}
```

Method has no knowledge of the instance `sContext` object.